# E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repo.jellyfin.org/debian/buster: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/jellyfin.asc !=

Tags: debian, apt, debian-buster

E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repo.jellyfin.org/debian/buster: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/jellyfin.asc !=

E: The list of sources could not be read.

This thing pops up when i try to install, update or do anything with apt.
I tried removing the key and reinstaling it. Like in this post https://jellyfin.org/posts/jellyfin-apt-key/. But with no success.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted every source-list and jellyfin keys
using  `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extrepo_jellyfin.sources`

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me after a failed Wine installation.  To fix the problem, I went through my apt folder and searched for every reference to Wine, then modified the sudo command referenced above to delete every reference to Wine in any of the subfolders.  It took a bit of experimentation with the text (learning what words/terms to include, remove, or substitute), but it worked in the end!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the sources for skype (yes, I still need to use that).
The problem is that there were two files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ which identified the same repository (https://repo.skype.com/deb), one of them with gpg keys and the other one without them. Apparently apt dislikes that and report "conflicting values".

So, search the files in said directory for the jellyfin repository. You will find more than one reference. And one of them will be wrong. Get rid of it. And that's it!